# Cufon Collaborate-Regular JQuery Placement

Tags: jquery, fonts, cufon

In The PSD which i have ...
There are Text which use 
**Collaborate-Regular None** 
and 
**Collaborate-Regular Sharp** 
How to use JQuery to replace those Font ??

Because i use jquery :

Cufon.replace('.CF_ColReg',{fontFamily: 'Colaborate-Regular' });

And default it use  **Collaborate-Regular Sharp**

I just want to know how so it can use **Collaborate-Regular None**  or **Collaborate-Regular Crisp** or **Collaborate-Regular Strong** or **Collaborate-Regular Smooth**
Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), quoting the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info), is a JavaScript library used for "DOM traversal, event handling, animation, and ajax interactions" - it is **not** used for embedding custom font into your websites.

With Cufon, you can embed the font into your website - just follow the [instruction on the website](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/) carefully, and you should be fine. Alternatively, you can use `@font-face` technology to do the same in more simply. [Collaboration is available on FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Colaborate), and their prepackaged `@font-face` kits are extremely easy to use.

Addressing the last part of your question, those are **not** different fonts you're looking at, or different weights, even. Those are different **[anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_aliasing) modes** offered by Photoshop. In general, anti-aliasing options are controlled at the Operating System level, so there is no way you can affect how the browsers display those fonts in terms of how they're anti-aliased.